# Twitter API keeps sending me to localhost

Tags: twitter, meteor

I am having trouble using twitter sign in. 
I have configured everything, including the URL callback.

```
http://www.ideasparacr.com:80/_oauth/twitter?close
```

But when I try to sign up it keeps sending me to:

```
 http://localhost/_oauth/twitter?close&state (and a lot of keys after this)
```

Why does it keeps sending me to that url?
Also, I am trying implement Telescope Meteor if that can add anything useful.

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: What is this? `com:8080`

Comment: I read somewhere I needed to add the port to the URL.

Comment: I corrected it, it's 80.

Comment: Ok. Is it better now? Did you configured the URL callback on both dev.twitter.com and in your code? When did you update it? I guess you need to let Twitter more time before it takes effect?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I needed to set ROOT_URL=http://server.mydomain.com:3000 with my correct domain.

Thanks for the help.

Regards,
Daniel